# How do I get sudo -u $user to use the users env?

Tags: security, sudo

It seems when `sudo`ing down that using `sudo -u $user` that the environment of root is still being used. How can I make `sudo` use the users environment? as a special note not all users that I will be using this on have login shells.

Comment: Define 'environment'.  `# whoami => root # sudo -u user whoami => user`

Comment: @alex I figure `sudo -u user` is analogous to `su user` to switch the env in su you have to use `su - user`

Comment: But what do you mean with "the user's environment" if the user doesn't have a login shell?

Comment: @Thomas users can run programs even if they can't shell in... I believe `-u` also ignores groups... I tried something from root (using sudo -u down)  and it worked, apparently it didn't for the user... so I have to make sure I'm running commands in a way that would have all there limitations and environmental issues.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `sudo -i -u $user`

```
gerald@book:~$ env |grep HOME
HOME=/home/gerald
gerald@book:~$ sudo -u ubuntu env |grep HOME
HOME=/home/gerald
gerald@book:~$ sudo -i -u ubuntu env |grep HOME
HOME=/home/ubuntu
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work if they don't have a shell in `/etc/passwd` :( but it'll do I guess...

Comment: Looking at the man page, it seems that `-E` is the one that preserves the environment, i.e. all the environment variables etc are there, although it still doesn't set `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the calling user's.

Comment: `$SUDO_USER` can be used

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to prevent the command from being run from the user's home directory instead of the current directory?

Answer (score 4):

`man sudoers` on Debian mentions another possibility. Not sure which way around you want, but your question sounds like you would want to have the `env_reset` option from `/etc/sudoers` - the opposite is basically the `env_keep` list. In order to set the proper `HOME` you can use the `-H` option to `sudo` directly or, again in `sudoers`, with the `always_set_home` option.

Alternatively you could use `env_file` to specify an *exact* environment you want to pass. However, I think it is best if you check out the `env_*` options from `man sudoers`, because `/etc/sudoers` controls it all and that's the point to turn to.

Here's part of the context in which I use `env_reset` inside my `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults        !lecture
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        syslog=auth
Defaults        log_year
```

Answer (score 1):

When **sudo**ing environment variables are not preserved.

In my case, I use [here-document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

You put your actions such as `my_script.sh` inside your HERE DOCUMENT :

```
su -u some_user <<EOF
./my_script.sh
EOF
```

You should not put variable directly here, as they would be interpreted from your current user.

```
su -u some_user <<EOF
./my_script.sh $MY_VAR
EOF
```

If `$MY_VAR` is not set for the user running the script, it won't be set.

You variable must be called inside your scripts, or you must escape them with `\`.

Eg.

```
su -u some_user <<EOF
./my_script.sh \$MY_VAR
EOF
```

Here, `$MY_VAR` will have `some_user` contextual value.

Comment: Good answer. One small correction: It should be `su - some_user` instead of `su -u some_user`.